# Check http response code of Redirect URL with PHP/cURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I'm writing a script which checks an array of domain names using curl and returns their http codes.

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example2.com',  'http://www.example3.com');

$msg = "
<p><strong>URL Error Check</strong></p>
";  

//Set code colours
$code200 = '<span style="color: green;"> OK - ';
$code0 = '<span style="color: red;"> Undefined Error - ';
$code404 = '<span style="color: red;"> File Not Found - ';

foreach($urls as $value){
    $ch = curl_init($value);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($httpcode==301 || $httpcode==302){   
        $redirect = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
        $httpcode .='<br> Redirects to: <span style="color: orange;">'.$redirect;
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $msg .= $value.": <strong>".${code.$httpcode}.$httpcode."</strong></span><br><br>";
}

echo $msg;
```

When the code is 301 or 302 it returns the resolving url after the redirect. I'd like it to then check the final URL and return it's http code as well.

Can someone please suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this option for your curl-request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

With this option set to true, your request will not stop when a redirect occurs.

Comment: I already have this in the curl request. It currently returns the code of the first URL before following the redirect.

Comment: @JamieMoffat Are you sure? With follow location on, the http code should be the final http code, and the url will also be the final url from redirection.

Comment: Yes. at the moment the code above when `$urls = array('http://example.com');` it returns "http://example.com: 301, redirects to: https://example.com" where the second URL is the https:// of the first

Comment: I had similar issue. Your http code is the one from first URL because your request has a timeout set and it needs more than that. Just increase that value or remove it and check again.
If the time is not enough, it will simply stop in following redirects.